# Swiftui - app crashes when using .destructive Button in .swipeActions and @ObservedObject in child View

Tags: swiftui, core-data, combine

I have this `View` that displays a list of `Folders` fetched from CoreData.

```
private struct FolderView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest
    private var folders: FetchedResults<Folder>
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
                    
    init(keyword: Binding<String> ) {
        var predicates: [NSPredicate] = [NSPredicate(format: "isHidden = %d", false) ]
 
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
        let sortDiscriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdDate", ascending: true)]
        self._folders = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDiscriptors, predicate: predicate)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
      
            ForEach(folders) { folder in
                FolderNavigationLinkView(folder:folder)
                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                    Button(role: .destructive) {
                        withAnimation {
                            context.delete(folder)
                            try? context.save()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Delete")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a `NaivgationLink` view . If I use the folder as an `@ObservedObject`, the app crushes when deleting the folder from the `FolderView`.

** The destination is a `Text` view here. But in my code, destination is another view that edits folders or add new notes.**

```
struct FolderNavigationLinkView:View {
    private var title: String
    
    @ObservedObject private var folder: Folder
    
    init(folder: Folder) {
        self.title = folder.name ?? ""
        self.folder = folder
    }
    
    var body : some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: { Text(folder.name ?? "")}) {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(title).font(.system(size: 16).bold())
                Spacer()
                Text("\(folder.notes != nil ? folder.notes!.count: 0)")
                    .padding(.trailing)
            }
            .frame(minHeight: 50)
        }
        .padding(.trailing)
    }
}
```

I am using `@ObservedObject`, because when adding a new note, I need to upadte how many notes a folder contains. (`Text("\(folder.notes != nil ? folder.notes!.count: 0)")`)

`Folder` is an entity that has `one to many` relationship with `Note`.

When deleting a folder, the app crushes. This following message displayed on the rigth side of `@main`.

`Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18d4adab0)`

Nothing is logged in the console.

So how to fix this bug?

### Update

I tried it without creating folder in `FolderNavigationLinkView`. It still crushes.

```
struct FolderNavigationLinkView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var folder: Folder
        
    var body : some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: { Text(folder.name ?? "")}) {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(folder.name ?? "").font(.system(size: 16).bold())
                Spacer()
                Text("\(folder.notes != nil ? folder.notes!.count: 0)")
                    .padding(.trailing)
            }
            .frame(minHeight: 50)
        }
        .padding(.trailing)
    }
}
```

### Update 2

This might be a bug in iOS. I used the  `.onDelete` view modifier instead of the `.swipeActions(edge: .trailing)` . It works and the app does not crushes.

It also works if you use `Button(role: .none)` instead of `Button(role: .destructive)` in any edge of the`.swipeActions`.

It happens that the bug is related to `@ObservedObject` and `Button(role: .destructive)` in `.swipeActions`.

**I prefer to use a `.desetrucive` Button in `swipeActions(.trailing)` view modifier to delete list item**.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks but it does not work.

Comment: What happens when you try this without using CoreData? e.g with a hardcoded array of `Folder`

Comment: @AshleyMills I created a simple class that has a property named `folders` which is a list of `Identifible` and `Observable` class named `TestFolder`.  It works.

Comment: Does it happen with you remove “withAnimation”?

Comment: @loremipsum yes!

Comment: I need to use both of the `swipeActions` and Delete should be .destructive @Cristik